# Memory of unreferenced Form not freed

Tags: garbage-collection, compact-framework

I have created a simple test-program with two Forms. One containing a button to start the procedure and on containing only an image (or in another testcase a byte[]). Both contain a timer to allow the rendering of the forms.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Instantiate and show Form2
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();

        // Dispose, force Collect and show (estimated) memory usage 
        form2.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The other Form only closes itself (there is an PictureBox in the .designer-Part):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // Alternative test
    // private byte[] bytes;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 0; 
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        //bytes = new byte[1024*1024];
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ignore;
    }
}
```

The Point is: it doesn't matter what exactly is in `Form2`: the memory usage rises and at one point I'll get an OutOfMemoryException (or in case of the PictureBox a `System.Exception` ending in

```
at Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
at System.Drawing.Bitmap._InitFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream mstream)
```

but that seems to be an OutOfMemoryException in a native call which is not thrown properly.)

I don't understand why. There is no reference left to the old instance of `Form2`, I call `Dispose` and yet the memory is not released.

I use CF 3.5 for this.

Comment: Does the behavior persist when you give the Timers an actual, reasonable interval?  What's the callstack when using a byte[] instead of an image?

Comment: Yes, I tried 1000ms. I suspected that the GC wouldn't kick in if the process was busy all the time, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Solved it, thank you for having a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, multiple things were at work here:

- The event handler for the Tick-event held an implicit reference to the form.

The timer1_Tick needs a reference to the form. As long as there is a reference to the form in the timer and a reference in the form to the pointer, the GC (at least the CF one, I did't test this on the regular Framework) cannot free the memory.

- The components where not disposed.

It seems it isn't enough to call `Dispose` on the form. I also had to call Dispose on the Timer to free all of its memory. [This is a bug.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/305534/smart-device-designer-does-not-add-objects-deriving-from-system-componentmodel-component-to-components-collection)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private byte[] bytes;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 0; 
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ignore;
        this.timer1.Tick -= timer1_Tick;
        this.timer1.Dispose();
        this.mainMenu1 = null;
    }
}
```